# can someone please help solving this issue

Tags: c++

i appeared for a campus placement exam few days ago. then while solving it. I found it quite difficult to solve. And atlast i unable to solve it.
the question is as follows:
suppose we input a string of n length. then we have to give second input.that is number of charecters after which space needs to put.
example input:

```
joebiden
3
```

expected output

```
joe bid en
```

i code something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    int space, con1 = 0, con2 = 0, con3 = 0, i = 0;
    cin >> str;
    cin >> space;
    con1 = str.size();
    for (con2 = 0; con2 < con1; con2++) {
        for (con3 = 0; con3 < space; con3++) {
            cout << str[con2];
            if (con3 < (space - 1)) {
                con2++;
            }
        }

        cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use a title that describes the specific problem. "can someone please help solving this issue" is so vague that it could be used for pretty much any question on this site. This means that (1) few people will be interested, and worse (2) future visitors with the same problem will not be able to find this question.

Comment: Please try to explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what the `if` (and the nested loops) does and why.

Comment: Use more descriptive variable names, what do `con1`, `con2`, `con3` and `i` represent? E.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ed5x5sEfq) would be easier for others (and perhaps you) to understand, `spaceCounter` is probably not a good name but I didn't understand the logic of what it was representing

Comment: Your program [does appear to produce the correct output](https://godbolt.org/z/K5vrzxsYG)? Or is it supposed to be `joe biden`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo operator to find on which index you should put space.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str;
  cin >> str;
  int space;
  cin >> space;
  int n = str.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i % space == 0) cout << " ";
    cout << str[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a working and also a shorter approach for your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string input; std::cin >> input; // Ask the user for input
    int segment_len; std::cin >> segment_len; // Ask the user for segment_len

    if (segment_len > 0)
    {
        for (int i = segment_len; i < input.size(); i += segment_len)
        {
            input.insert(i++, 1, ' ');
        }
    }

    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

This application firstly takes in a string, then the segment length, and then adds a space after every segment_len characters.